# How to split an image dataset into train and test sets?

Tags: machine-learning, keras

I'm working on 256_ObjectCategories dataset from Caltech. They have organised all the images in 256 categories in different folders. I'm using ImageDataGenerator from Keras to load the dataset but I'm not able to split it into training and testing using the same. How can I do this in a terminal without moving images or changing directories? Any help is appreciated. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 1):

This doesn´t seem to be possible out of the box with ImageDataGenerator right now. See this thread: https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/5862

User AloshkaD suggests as a workaround that you create an index list with glob: `rasterList = glob.glob(os.path.join(path_of_your_image_directory, '*.jpg'))`, split that programmatically and feed the validation part of that list into the `validation_data` parameter of fit_generator().