# How to split an image dataset in X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test by tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, image-processing, keras, artificial-intelligence

How can I split the image data into X_train, Y_train, X_test and Y_test?

I am using keras with tensorflow backend

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to split an image dataset into train and test sets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44666703/how-to-split-an-image-dataset-into-train-and-test-sets)

Answer (score 6):

For example, you have folder like this

```
full_dataset
|--horse (40 images)
|--donkey (30 images)
|--cow ((50 images)
|--zebra (70 images)
```

FIRST WAY

```
import glob
horse = glob.glob('full_dataset/horse/*.*')
donkey = glob.glob('full_dataset/donkey/*.*')
cow = glob.glob('full_dataset/cow/*.*')
zebra = glob.glob('full_dataset/zebra/*.*')

data = []
labels = []

for i in horse:   
    image=tf.keras.preprocessing.image.load_img(i, color_mode='RGB', 
    target_size= (280,280))
    image=np.array(image)
    data.append(image)
    labels.append(0)
for i in donkey:   
    image=tf.keras.preprocessing.image.load_img(i, color_mode='RGB', 
    target_size= (280,280))
    image=np.array(image)
    data.append(image)
    labels.append(1)
for i in cow:   
    image=tf.keras.preprocessing.image.load_img(i, color_mode='RGB', 
    target_size= (280,280))
    image=np.array(image)
    data.append(image)
    labels.append(2)
for i in zebra:   
    image=tf.keras.preprocessing.image.load_img(i, color_mode='RGB', 
    target_size= (280,280))
    image=np.array(image)
    data.append(image)
    labels.append(3)

data = np.array(data)
labels = np.array(labels)

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, ytrain, ytest = train_test_split(data, labels, test_size=0.2,
                                                random_state=42)
```

SECOND WAY

```
image_generator = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1/255, validation_split=0.2)    

train_dataset = image_generator.flow_from_directory(batch_size=32,
                                                 directory='full_dataset',
                                                 shuffle=True,
                                                 target_size=(280, 280), 
                                                 subset="training",
                                                 class_mode='categorical')

validation_dataset = image_generator.flow_from_directory(batch_size=32,
                                                 directory='full_dataset',
                                                 shuffle=True,
                                                 target_size=(280, 280), 
                                                 subset="validation",
                                                 class_mode='categorical')
```

Main drawback from Second way, you can't use for display a picture. It will error if you write `validation_dataset[1]`. But it worked if I use first way : `X_test[1]`

Comment: What if I have 100 classes how the  first way can be automated kindly help

Comment: I'm sorry I dont know, please kindly use second way

Comment: i have csv file ? ok Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use tensorflow or keras to divide your dataset.
If you have sklearn package installed then you can simply use it:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X = ...
Y = ...
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.2)
```

You can also use numpy for the same purpose:

```
import numpy
X = ...
Y = ...
test_size = 0.2
train_nsamples = (1-test_size) * len(Y)
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = X[:train_nsamples,:], X[train_nsamples:, :], Y[:train_nsamples, ], Y[train_nsamples:,]
```

Good Luck!

Comment: please provide X.. and Y.. code for explanation i am beginner , how to encode categorical data etc so i can pass to keras and apply data augmentation