# ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential_6 is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 1

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I am trying to create a convolutional neural network for binary classification that can distinguish the difference between a normal face and the face of someone who is having a stroke.

Following the approach used in [this tutorial](https://towardsdatascience.com/build-your-own-convolution-neural-network-in-5-mins-4217c2cf964f), I have created the CNN, which works when fed with the MNIST dataset. I have also followed the approach suggested in [this StackOverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60841589/15228787) to import my images into the neural network. Shown below is my code.

```
Strokes = glob.glob('C:\\Users\\Colin\\CNNImages\\Strokes\\*.*')
RegularFaces = glob.glob('C:\\Users\\Colin\\CNNImages\\RegularFaces\\*.*')

data = []
labels = []

for i in Strokes:   
    image=tf.keras.preprocessing.image.load_img(i, color_mode='rgb', 
    target_size= (128,128))
    image=np.array(image)
    data.append(image)
    labels.append(0)
for i in RegularFaces:   
    image=tf.keras.preprocessing.image.load_img(i, color_mode='rgb', 
    target_size= (128,128))
    image=np.array(image)
    data.append(image)
    labels.append(1)


data = np.array(data)
labels = np.array(labels)

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(data, labels, test_size=0.2,
                                                random_state=42)

batch_size = 128
num_classes = 2
epochs = 12

# input image dimensions
img_rows, img_cols = 128, 128

x_train = x_train.reshape(864,128,128,3)
x_test = x_test.reshape(216,128,128,3)

print('x_train shape:', x_train.shape)
print(x_train.shape[0], 'train samples')
print(x_test.shape[0], 'test samples')

# convert class vectors to binary class matrices
y_train = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train, num_classes)
y_test = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_test, num_classes)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3),
                 activation='relu',
                 input_shape=(28,28,1)))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss=keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy,
              optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adadelta(),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(x_train, y_train,
          batch_size=batch_size,
          epochs=epochs,
          verbose=1,
          validation_data=(x_test, y_test))

score = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, verbose=0)
print('Test loss:', score[0])
print('Test accuracy:', score[1])
```

When I run the code, I receive the following error: `ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential_6 is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 1 but received input with shape (None, 128, 128, 3)`. How would I go about stopping this error from occurring?

Comment: `color_mode='grayscale'` and don't reshape with 3 channels, reshape with 1 channel

Comment: `axis -1` means the final dimension, the channel dimension. The error says that you must feed the model with 3 channels while it is expected to get only one.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line of code:-

```
model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3),
             activation='relu',
             input_shape=(28,28,1)))
```

to this:-

```
model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3),
             activation='relu',
             input_shape=(28,28,3)))
```

Your `input_shape` argument in model l must be consistent with the image dimensions which you have transmuted above.